# Overlapping issue in employee task schedule Using Power Query

Tags: overloading, powerquery

I have a schedule for employees' tasks, every employee starts his work shift from 7:00 to 15:00, I have an issue with an employee who has 3 tasks with start/end times of 7 am-11 am, 10 am-1 pm, and 11 am-3 pm then 10 am-1 pm overlaps with both task times 7 am-11 am and 11 am-3 pm, how could I ignore the overlapped task time

```
|Employee ID|Tasks    |Task Start      |Task End        |
|-----------+---------+----------------+----------------|
|123456     |Break    |2/12/23 7:00 AM |2/12/23 11:00 AM|
|123456     |Job Order|2/12/23 10:00 AM|2/12/23 1:00 PM |
|123456     |Waiting  |2/12/23 12:00 PM|2/12/23 3:00 PM |
|123654     |Job Order|2/12/23 7:00 AM |2/12/23 3:00 PM |
```

I've tried applying the below solution, but it produces an error

```
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Employee ID", "Task Start"}, {{"Tasks", each _, type table [Employee ID=text, Task Start=datetime, Task End=datetime]}}),
#"Expanded Tasks" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Tasks", {"Employee ID", "Task Start", "Task End"}, {"Employee ID", "Task Start", "Task End"}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded Tasks",{{"Employee ID", Order.Ascending}, {"Task Start", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Index", 1, 1),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Overlap", each if [Index] = 1 then "No Overlap" 
                                            else if [Task Start] >= List.Min(Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index", each [Employee ID]=[Employee ID] and [Index]<=[Index]-1 and [Task End]>=[Task Start])[Task End]) 
                                                and [Task End] <= List.Max(Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index", each [Employee ID]=[Employee ID] and [Index]<=[Index]-1 and [Task Start]<=[Task End])[Task Start]) then "Overlap" 
                                            else "No Overlap"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each [Overlap] = "No Overlap") in "Filtered Rows"`
```

`error: Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value null to type Logical. Details: Value= Type=[Type]`

the expected output is to set a flag by adding a custom column "Overlapped" beside the middle one that overlapped with the 1st task that has the start time of the work shift `7 am` and the last task that has the end time `3 pm`

result e.g.

```
|Employee ID|Tasks    |Task Start      |Task End        |Flag       |
|-----------+---------+----------------+----------------+-----------|
|123456     |Break    |2/12/23 7:00 AM |2/12/23 11:00 AM|Not Overlap|
|123456     |Job Order|2/12/23 10:00 AM|2/12/23 1:00 PM |Overlap    |
|123456     |Waiting  |2/12/23 12:00 PM|2/12/23 3:00 PM |Not Overlap|
|123654     |Job Order|2/12/23 7:00 AM |2/12/23 3:00 PM |Not Overlap|
```

Comment: What do you mean by "***ignore***"? Please show a screenshot of your  final expected results given the data you have presented and the necessity of ignoring the overlap time. Are you trying to just sum the hours the employee is present? Or something else?

Comment: the ignoration is to add a flag to the overlapped time to able filtering it. so by this flag, it will be located beside the 2nd row in our example

Comment: Why not also the third row?

Comment: because I need to keep the tasks that determine the work shift time from 7 am to 3 pm

Comment: What about other scenarios? What if Task 2 ends at 3:00PM and there is no Task3? It might be better if you could provide a more comprehensive list of possible scenarios.

Comment: you are right there are a lot of scenarios, but simply I need to keep the 2 tasks that set the work shift time frame even if these 2 tasks are overlapped e.g. 1st task from 7 am-11 am and 2nd task from 10 am-3 pm so I'll keep both as not overlapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

- We label **Not Overlap** if the Task either starts at 7 AM or ends at 3 PM.
- For other tasks, we label **Overlap** if the Task ends after the previous task begins

*It works for the scenario you provided, and you can modify it for scenarios that you have not provided*

```
let

//change next two lines to reflect actual data source and format
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table19"]}[Content],
    #"Trim Headers" = Table.RenameColumns(Source, List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each {_, Text.Trim(_)})),
    
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Trim Headers",{
        {"Employee ID", Int64.Type}, {"Tasks", type text}, {"Task Start", type datetime}, {"Task End", type datetime}}),

//The "magic" happens here
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Employee ID"}, {
        {"Overlap Test", (t)=>
            let 
                #"Start Shift" = Date.From(t[Task Start]{0}) & #time(7,0,0),
                #"End Shift" = Date.From(t[Task Start]{0}) & #time(15,0,0),
                #"Offset End Time" = Table.FromColumns(
                    Table.ToColumns(t) & {{null} & List.RemoveLastN(t[Task End],1)},
                    type table[Employee ID=Int64.Type, Tasks=text, Task Start=datetime, Task End=datetime,Shifted Task End=datetime]),
                #"Overlap Time" = Table.AddColumn(#"Offset End Time","Overlap", each 
                    if [Shifted Task End] > [Task Start] 
                        and 
                            ([Task Start] > #"Start Shift" and [Task End] < #"End Shift")
                        then "Overlap"
                        else "Not Overlap"
                    
                    ),
                #"Remove Shifted Task" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Overlap Time",{"Shifted Task End"})
            in 
                #"Remove Shifted Task", type table[Employee ID=Int64.Type, Tasks=text, Task Start=datetime, Task End=datetime, Overlap=text]}    
        }),

//expand the grouped tables
    #"Expanded Overlap" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Overlap Test", {"Tasks", "Task Start", "Task End", "Overlap"})
in
    #"Expanded Overlap"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want ?  For an employee on a date, it takes the minimum start time and the maximum end time ignoring task.   Would not work if there were time gaps

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Employee ID", Int64.Type}, {"Tasks", type text}, {"Task Start", type datetime}, {"Task End", type datetime}}),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Task Date", each Date.From([Task Start])),
#"Grouped Rows1" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom1", {"Employee ID", "Task Date"}, {{"Task Start", each List.Min([Task Start]), type nullable datetime}, {"Task End", each List.Max([Task End]), type nullable datetime}})
in  #"Grouped Rows1"
```

Comment: can we keep the ```task``` and only set a flag beside the overlapped one in order to filter it, as the task field is needed in my data

Comment: Then you'd need to explain better.  Who gets a flag if three row partially overlap each other?

Comment: I've added more details about the desired output.